# Java boolean static error

Tags: java

The code gives a boolean error when I try to run it. It says boolean can not be adressed with static. What could be the answer.?

```
package csd;
class Uti {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean result;

        result = Sample.foo() && Sample.bar();
            System.out.printf("result%b%n",result); 
    }

    class Sample {

        public static boolean foo() {
            System.out.println("foo");
            return true;
        }

        public static boolean bar() {
            System.out.println("bar");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method foo cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type

Comment: can you show the exact error message? where does it give this error? is there a reason your Uti class isn't public?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method foo cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type

Comment: Well, your `Sample` class is an inner class, and the error message says such classes can't contain static methods.

Comment: @SinaCengiz doesn't that error say it all? put those static methods in your Uti class and declare it to be public, or put our other class in it's own file and declare that public

Comment: @Stultuske that does solve the problem, but not it does not explain why the current attempt is not working. There is a third option (declaring the inenr class `Sample` static).

Comment: Ineer class must also be `static`

Comment: @Turing85 no, the error message already explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks , working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making your `Sample` class static will resolve your error:

```
class Uti {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    boolean result;

    result = Sample.foo() && Sample.bar();
    System.out.printf("result%b%n",result); 
  }

  static class Sample {

    public static boolean foo() {
      System.out.println("foo");

      return true;
    }

    public static boolean bar() 

    {
      System.out.println("bar");

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Making it a top level class will also work:

```
class Sample {

  public static boolean foo() {
    System.out.println("foo");

    return true;
  }

  public static boolean bar() 

  {
    System.out.println("bar");

    return false;
  }
}

class Uti {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    boolean result;

    result = Sample.foo() && Sample.bar();
    System.out.printf("result%b%n",result); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a compilation error in your code, you can fix your problem by adding a static modifier to parent type like this in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        boolean result;

        result = Sample.foo() && Sample.bar();
                System.out.printf("result%b%n",result); 
        }
    static class Sample {

    public static boolean foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");

    return true;
    }

    public static boolean bar() 

    {
    System.out.println("bar");

    return false;
    }
    }
```